# Group message in Queue like RabbitMQ/Kafka/Redis

Tags: java, apache-kafka, redis, rabbitmq, queue

I got problem when using message queue like kafka, rabbitmq, redis

I want to group message into multi group by tenant ID, cause each message in queue/topic belong to difference tenant, each tenant have limit number message thought put per second.

If i separate multi queue, it too many queue exits on system.

How can i group message in multi queue/topic, and get bundle message.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it possible to set a unique ID for each tenant's message? Then all are sent to a single queue, and consumers process the messages according to the unique identifier of the tenant.This is my thought, your business may be more complicated.

Comment: each message have unique id @HuaJFrame , but if use single queue you can't get enough message for 1 tenant ( cause each tenant have limit though put, if we get full limit each time, it will be the most optimal )